# Got error: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am getting following error when i use `CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPage)` for some files. Any work around to fix this issue?

```
FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Error 2 looks like `errno` 2 which is "File not found".  Please post more code to confirm this.