# IBM Worklight: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2 when using custom fonts

Tags: ios, fonts, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been using two versions of my WL App; one for UAT & other for Production. From few days I am getting this error only in the UAT version. However, the code for both versions remain same.

Because of this, the UAT App fonts are coming different.

I am using  **Benton** and **Helvetica** using CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman';
  src: url('fonts/helveticaneueltstdroman/helveticaneueltstdroman.eot');
  src: url('fonts/helveticaneueltstdroman/helveticaneueltstdroman.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/helveticaneueltstdroman/helveticaneueltstdroman.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/helveticaneueltstdroman/helveticaneueltstdroman.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/helveticaneueltstdroman/helveticaneueltstdroman.svg#helveticaneueltstdroman') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BentonSansBold';
    src: url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-bold.svg#BentonSansBold') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BentonSansRegular';
    src: url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Benton/bentonsans-regular.svg#BentonSansRegular') format('svg');
}
```

Below is the error message

```
May  9 10:56:22 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] ondeviceready event dispatched\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: \{\
        appVersionPref = "1.0";\
        freeSpace = 13073145856;\
        wlSkinLoaderChecksum = "(null)";\
        wlSkinName = default;\
    \}\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] Application did not define an i18n messages object, skipping translation.\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] wlclient init started\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] Read cookies: null\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] CookieMgr read cookies: \{\}\
May  9 10:56:26 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Error>: FT_Open_Face failed: error 2.\
May  9 10:56:27 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] Request [http://172.20.10.6:9082/myApp/apps/services/api/abcApp/iphone/init]\
May  9 10:56:30 iPhone abcApp[7054] <Warning>: [LOG] indicatorIdx =4122\
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267702/got-error-ft-open-face-failed-error-2) and looked for missing font files. But all files are there.

Any suggestion, what could go wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing both apps on the device device or iOS simulator? Try cleaning the project in Xcode before building and running it, or/also make sure to reset the simulator. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Yes testing on device. Even have deleted Apps and then re-installed but no benefit. Plus right now, someone had correct fonts on his device with UAT version, but after getting **Direct Update** the font has been changed. It Looks code generation issue. I removed/deleted iPhone environment from the consumer Studio 5.0.5 and then re-added, and re-uploaded the App on console, now when i got update still face issue. Logs showing same exception and fonts are not correct.

Comment: are you using custom fonts in your application? how do you define them? you'll need to better explain your application, what it is, etc... edit the question with more details.

Comment: are you testing the uat and production apps on the same device? what is the ios version?

Comment: also add information how the app is being built for uat and production, there may be differences the cause it.

Comment: @Idan, iOS 5 & 6, testing on multiple devices and have same behavior. One a device i install either Test or Production App one by one, but not both altogether at the same time. Built Process: it is the same for both versions, only Workspace is different and different URL in the application-descriptor.xml.

Comment: Does this issue always happen after getting direct update?

Comment: if it always happen - irregardless of direct update, then i suggest you starat playing with the fonts in the css - maybe a specific set or line ther trigger this error...

Comment: yes it does happen through Direct Update,. I am checking it and will update you. thanks

Comment: did you manage to solve this puzzling question?

Comment: No, still same issue. I have given fonts in CSS already. It happens on my PC only but another developer's PC, it generates correctly. We both have exactly same environment and versions. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abdul, as you say this happens only on your machine and not on another developer's machine, this sounds more like an environment issue than anything else.

I have also found the following question: [Adding custom fonts to my iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595096/adding-custom-fonts-to-my-iphone-application)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Idan. Basically my CVS had corrupted fonts files :( so i simply recopied again and it worked fine.